# Stop text changing size when swapping language in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, flutter-layout, mobile-development

I have an onboarding system where the user can pick a language, when scrolling through the options, the text items on-screen display in the selected language. The problem is when the user goes to Hindi, the text size changes and alters the position/layout. This doesn't happen with any of the EU languages. The effect is quite jarring. Is there any simple way to fix this?

[***Here is a video demo of the issue, it might not be too easy to notice the difference in the images below***](https://youtube.com/shorts/8TA28m-dG9s?feature=share)

[image: English Language (OK)]
[image: Spanish Language (OK)]
[image: Hindi Language (ISSUE)]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:overpowered/pre_onboarding/onboarding_screen_1.dart';
import 'package:overpowered/pre_onboarding/onboarding_screen_2.dart';
import 'package:overpowered/pre_onboarding/onboarding_screen_3.dart';
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class OnBoardingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoardingScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OnBoardingScreen> createState() => _OnBoardingScreenState();
}

class _OnBoardingScreenState extends State<OnBoardingScreen> {
  final PageController _controller = PageController();

  bool onFirst = true;
  bool onLast = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var translations = AppLocalizations.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView(
            controller: _controller,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(
                () {
                  onFirst = (index == 0);
                  onLast = (index == 2);
                },
              );
            },
            children: const [
              OnboardingScreen1(),
              OnboardingScreen2(),
              OnboardingScreen3(),
            ],
          ),
          if (onFirst)
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment(-0.8, 0.9),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: 0.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                  child: Text(
                    translations!.back,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFD0FD3E),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          else
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment(-0.8, 0.9),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  _controller.previousPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeIn,
                  );
                },
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: 1.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                  child: Text(
                    translations!.back,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFD0FD3E),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment(0, 0.885),
            child: SmoothPageIndicator(
              controller: _controller,
              count: 3,
              effect: const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                dotColor: Color(0xFFD0FD3E),
                activeDotColor: Color(0xFFD0FD3E),
                radius: 0.0,
                dotWidth: 16.0,
                dotHeight: 4.0,
                spacing: 10.0,
                expansionFactor: 2.25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (onLast)
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment(0.8, 0.9),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {},
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: 0.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                  child: Text(
                    translations.next,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFD0FD3E),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          else
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment(0.8, 0.9),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  _controller.nextPage(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                    curve: Curves.easeIn,
                  );
                },
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: 1.0,
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                  child: Text(
                    translations.next,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFFD0FD3E),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess - it depends on font you are using (hindi symbols is smaller in default font). You can try using custom font

Comment: This is not an issue. It's just the font you are using. Most of the languages like German, etc. all have English Words so the font is scaled properly. In terms of Hindi, Bangla, Arabic, you will see text layout taking more or less space as the words are not in English. You have to probably create a custom font that supports English n Hindi letters in the same way.